# How to integrate curl.js with server-side jinja2 templating

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2, curl.js

I have a Python-based Flask web application that uses Jinja2 to perform templating on the server-side.

I would like to improve my Javascript and CSS loading by using curl.js to load JS and CSS asynchronously.

Is there a specific, well-defined method for doing this?

Comment: Like any other JS file I guess, what is stopping you adding it in to your base template like you would with a normal <script>

Comment: Well, the web application I'm working makes extensive (Probably too extensive, previous devs work) use of the template inheritance, import and include features of Jinja2.

Right now this means that the site is a mish-mash of re-used server-side templates that include JavaScript segments along with with the HTML it works on. It's all rather messy and I'm trying to clean it up.

Comment: Well it may be worth re-facotring that. If you want to include some extra JS across the board your going to have this issue regardless.

Comment: Ah, so basically what I'm already doing :-)

I've added a little extension to our Jinja2 env that allows me to replace <script> and <link> elements with a call like {{ add_to_resource_bundle('BUNDLE', '/path/to/resource') }} and then call another function to obtain a list of links at the end of <body> or <head>. I think it will be easy to use with curl.js.

When it comes to libraries like jQuery, are there AMD versions available somewhere or should I just curl them using the js! form?

Comment: jQuery [is AMD compatible](http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html)

Comment: Most popular libs have AMD support built-in.  curl.js also supports most CommonJS-formatted modules and global scripts via "loaders".  See this document[1] and take a peek at the code comments for more info.

[1] https://github.com/cujojs/curl/tree/master/src/curl/loader